# Is there a way to determine the LCS of three based on the LCS-s of all three pairs?

Tags: dynamic-programming, approximation, edit-distance

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet of some symbols, and let $\mathrm{lcs}$ denote the length of the longest common subsequence of two or more sequences defined on $\Sigma$. For some $A,B,C\in\Sigma^{\star}$, given $\mathrm{lcs}\!\left(A,B\right)$, $\mathrm{lcs}\!\left(B,C\right)$ and $\mathrm{lcs}\!\left(C,A\right)$, what can be said about $\mathrm{lcs}\!\left(A,B,C\right)$? Obviously, $\mathrm{lcs}\!\left(A,B,C\right)\leqslant \mathrm{min}\!\left\{\mathrm{lcs}\!\left(A,B\right),\mathrm{lcs}\!\left(B,C\right),\mathrm{lcs}\!\left(C,A\right)\right\}$, but what else?

The standard DP approach reduces the LCS problem to *smaller* LCS problems, where *smaller* means **shorter** sequences. So here I ask if it can somehow be reduced to LCS problems with **fewer** sequences? Any research and/or known results on this question?

Comment: Compare $A=12,B=13,C=23$ to $A=12,B=13,C=14$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sorry, didn't get what you mean?

Comment: I gave two examples in which $\mathrm{lcs}(A,B)=\mathrm{lcs}(A,C)=\mathrm{lcs}(B,C) = 1$, but in the first example $\mathrm{lcs}(A,B,C)=0$, and in the second one $\mathrm{lcs}(A,B,C)=1$.

Comment: I see. In your comment, I was reading "twelve" instead of "one, two". But anyway, there might be some tight inequalities (maybe involving the number of symbols in $\Sigma$), though the $\mathrm{lcs}$-s of pairs does not define the $\mathrm{lcs}$ of the triple.

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is infinite, then a similar set-based construction shows that you cannot deduce anything more about $\mathrm{lcs}(A,B,C)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Agree, and what about finite $\Sigma$? Particularly when $\Sigma=\left\{0,1\right\}$?

Comment: I don’t know. The answer is less immediate.

Comment: I've searched the web a little and seems this topic is not elaborated enough.

Answer (score 3):

If $|\Sigma| \geq 3$, then for any non-negative integers $x \leq x_{AB}, x_{AC}, x_{BC}$ we can find strings $A,B,C$ such that $\operatorname{lcs}(A,B,C) = x$, $\operatorname{lcs}(A,B) = x_{AB}$, $\operatorname{lcs}(A,C) = x_{AC}$, $\operatorname{lcs}(B,C) = x_{BC}$:
\begin{align}
A &= a^x b^{x_{AC} - x} c^{x_{AB} - x} \\
B &= a^{x_{BC}} c^{x_{AB} - x} \\
C &= a^{x_{BC}} b^{x_{AC} - x}
\end{align}
where $a,b,c$ are different letters in $\Sigma$.

However, if $|\Sigma|=2$ and  $\operatorname{lcs}(A,B) \ge 1$, $\operatorname{lcs}(A,C) \ge 1$, $\operatorname{lcs}(B,C) \ge 1$, then $\operatorname{lcs}(A,B, C) \ge 1$.

Comment: Nice construction!

Comment: If $|\Sigma|=2$, $\operatorname{lcs}(A,B,C) \ge\frac12\min(\operatorname{lcs}(A,B), \operatorname{lcs}(A,C), \operatorname{lcs}(B,C))$.